# WhatsApp 2.12.112 multiple message select?

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp, nokia-lumia-820

I am looking for option multiple message select for forwarding and deleting purpose.
But I am unable to find it, If anyone knows, How to do it ? Please let me know

As per new releases notes we can do this functionality

Please check this link for version specific notes
http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/whatsapp-v2-12-112-windows-phone-brings-bug-fixes-feature-enhancements-download-1516288

I did long hold tapping on message but didn't saw such option or in any WhatsApp setting.

I installed this version and having 8.1 OS.

Please correct me, If I am understanding release notes improperly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the very edge of a particular message. This, selects that message and brings up the checklist for other messages as well.

Like this: [image]

This is the same way as we are used to selecting the messages and mails in their respective applications.